# How to test catch block in redux-sagas generator function test cases using chai?

Tags: javascript, redux, chai, redux-saga

```
export function* testGeneratorFunction() {
   try {
       yield put(showSuccess(success));
   } catch (error) {
       yield put(showError(error));
   }
}
```

In the above function i need to test the catch block. I have to test whether showError() function is called or not.

Comment: Is this question about "How to simulate throwing error"? Or is it about "How to test `yield put(showError(error));` when error happens"? If it is the later one, can you attach some code of `showError()`? (what does it return?)

Answer (score 3):

There is a decent chapter on [Error Handling](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/docs/basics/ErrorHandling.html) in the manual. In short, you can use `.throw` instead of `.next` to trigger the `catch` block in your saga:

```
assert.deepEqual(
  gen.throw({message: "error!").value, // <-- notice the throw instead of next
  put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_REQUEST_FAILED', error }),
  "fetchProducts should yield an Effect put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_REQUEST_FAILED', error })"
)
```

I'm not familiar with Chai syntax, but for instance using Jest's `expect` it would be:

```
expect(gen.throw({message: "server ded"}).value).toEqual(
  put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_REQUEST_FAILED', error })
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use an helper library for that, such as [redux-saga-testing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-saga-testing).

*Disclaimer: I wrote this library to solve that exact same problem*

For your specific example, using Jest (but works the same for Mocha), you would write:

```
import sagaHelper from 'redux-saga-testing';
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { showSuccess, showError } from './my-actions';
import { api } from './my-api';

function* testGeneratorFunction() {
    try {
        const data = yield call(api);
        yield put(showSuccess(data));
    } catch (e) {
        yield put(showError(e.message));
    }   
}

describe('When testing a Saga that throws an error', () => {
    const it = sagaHelper(testGeneratorFunction());

    it('should have called the API first, which will throw an exception', result => {
        expect(result).toEqual(call(api));
        return new Error('Something went wrong');
    });

    it('and then trigger an error action with the error message', result => {
        expect(result).toEqual(put(showError('Something went wrong')));
    });
});

describe('When testing a Saga and it works fine', () => {
    const it = sagaHelper(testGeneratorFunction());

    it('should have called the API first, which will return some data', result => {
        expect(result).toEqual(call(api));
        return 'some data';
    });

    it('and then call the success action with the data returned by the API', result => {
        expect(result).toEqual(put(showSuccess('some data')));
    });
});
```

I modified your example slightly, because "put" would never throw an exception.

In real life, a call to an API or some other logic would be more likely to throw an exception.

You'll find plenty of other examples (more complex ones) on the [project's GitHub.](https://github.com/antoinejaussoin/redux-saga-testing)

Comment: I would really like to see a solution that *does not* use a helper library